# Emulating braced list initialization before C++11 STL

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, std

In pre C++11's standard library, is there any way to make a class constructor from an `std::initializer_list`-like object, which would work when with braced list initialization like `std::initializer_list` does?

I *can* use C++11 (and even C++14) language features. However, with some projects I'm still using libstdc++ on Xcode, which has no C++11 support, since I need to support OS X 10.6.

Comment: If your class is an [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Otherwise, no.

Comment: You can easily create a class emulating `std::initializer_list`, ***but*** braced list initialization is part of the compiler and not the standard library. It is the compiler that takes the braced initializer list and creates the `std::initializer_list` object.

Comment: I can't see a way to do it without the language support that was added in C++11 to make it possible.  Of course boost does have an "solution": http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I changed the title to better reflect the actual need, thanks!

Comment: Idea: Since variadic templates *are* supported, maybe the way to go is to make variadic constructors where an "initializer_list" is desired? With the small difference that the list of parameters when calling this constructor should go in parentheses, not in braces.

Comment: @Danra Doing that does involve recursion so if it is a big list the compiler is going to have to do a lot of work.

Comment: @Danra Variadic templates were introduced in `C++11`.

Comment: @Galik See my question: "I *can* use C++11 (and even C++14) language features. However, with some projects I'm still using libstdc++ on Xcode, which has no C++11 support". With Xcode, if you use libstdc++, you can use the new C++11 language features, Variadic Templates included, just without the supporting STL that comes with C++11.

Comment: It's as undefined as it gets, but you can probably just take an `std::initializer_list` implementation from a later libstdc++ version and use it. The library-side code for that is trivial; the magic is almost all in the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you have C++11 as a language feature, but the standard library doesn't support it. So you're asking if you can construct containers from `initializer_list`s.

Yes, but it won't be with the same syntax. This function would be sufficient:

```
template<typename Container>
Container from_list(std::initializer_list<typename Container::value_type> il)
{
  return Container(il.begin(), il.end());
}

auto vec = from_list<std::vector<int>>({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
```

Standard library containers have constructors that work with iterator pairs. So this should work with any such container.

However, this assumes that the standard library actually has the `initializer_list` type. If it doesn't, then you're out of luck.

Comment: there's no std::initializer_list in the pre-c++11 stdlibc++ which ships with Xcode.

Comment: @Danra: "*If it doesn't, then you're out of luck.*"